# Java ProcessBuilder: environment set correctly but still command not found

Tags: java, path, environment-variables, processbuilder

I am having troubles with Java's ProcessBuilder on an Eclipse plugin I'm developing.
I correctly set the environment before calling the start() method, but when I run the program, it always returns a command not found error.

When I call the command via command line it works perfectly.

When I start the eclipse with the environment as I require, the command is found and the program works fine.

Only when I set the environment programatically, the program fails.

Here is what I have:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("my_command", file, output);
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("PATH", env.get("PATH") + File.pathSeparator + env1 + File.pathSeparator + env2);
Process p = pb.start();
...
```

where, `env1` and `env2` are the paths I want to add to the PATH variable...

What is wrong in this code?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the environment you set on the ProcessBuilder is only what is passed to the new process but not what is used by the builder itself. Try setting the [environment variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) of your Java process before trying to start the new process.

Edit:

Seeing that it may not be possible to alter the Java process's environment, I believe you have to come up with some work-around.

When you already know the path(s) you are looking for you can of course figure out the full path to `"my_command"` yourself, about so:

```
String commandString;

if ( new File(env1 + "/my_command").isFile() ) {
  commandString = env1 + "/my_command";
} else
if ( new File(env2 + "/my_command").isFile() ) {
  commandString = env2 + "/my_command";
}

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandString, file, output);
```

Might be impractical though, if `"my_command"` may already be in one of the user's `PATH` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I think that is not possible to do in may case, given that the paths I want to add to the environment PATH may be added by the users in runtime... In any case, if I understand, the System.getenv() cannot be modified in runtime. Did I get it wrongly?

Comment: Only now I've seen this update on your response. Actually I came out to the same conclusion by myself after understanding how ProcessBuilder really works (which I have to say, it was based on your first answer). 
So, the environment that we set before calling `start()` is passed to the command executed within the process to start and **not** is used by the process that is currently running on the JVM (which is responsible for looking for the command in the process to start).